# How can I make and run a Vaadin+Jetty+Gradle project in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, jetty, vaadin

I have an ultimate edition of IntelliJ, with declared support of Jetty and Vaadin. But I can't make a hello project that runs on Jetty, Vaadin, Gradle.

I tried a Vaadin+Gradle project: 
https://github.com/johndevs/gradle-vaadin-plugin/wiki/Getting-Started-in-Intellij-IDEA. I can launch the Vaadin application by running

> gradle vaadinRun

in terminal. I can run the task from the Gradle window, too. After that its run configuration appears in the Gradle window and I can edit it and add a local Jetty sever. But that changes nothing in running vaadinRun.

How can I check if I had really added Jetty and it works? Maybe, I have to add something to the following Vaadin class?

```
@Theme("Gv_1")
public class Gv_1UI extends UI{

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request){
        Label lbl = new Label("Hello vaadin");
        setContent(lbl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

vaadinRun by default will automatically run an embedded server for you so there is no need to add another jetty server if you use vaadinRun.

When you run vaadinRun the server will remain listening to changes in the class files so whenever you re-compile your class files the server will refresh. In intellij when you have made a change to a class you can go to Build -> Recompile to recompile the change and that should trigger a server refresh. You can automate the re-compilation by checking the "Make project automatically" checkbox in intellij.

[image: Make project automatically]